# How would I display a Airplane seating chart?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, for-loop

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AirlineReservation {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        System.out.println("Enter n:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int[][] airplane = new int[n][4];

        for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%3d\t", i);
        }

        for(int j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
            System.out.println((j) + " -" + "       -" + "       -" + "      -");
        } 
    }
}
```

What I want is to have four numbers display on top (which it does), have the user enter some number and have that be the number of rows (which it does), and "-" for each open section.

I'm not sure how to do this and I have some of my j int on the first line which I do not want. Can someone give me a hand with this?

This is the output output:

```
Enter n:
5
  1       2       3      4  
1 -       -       -      -

2 -       -       -      -

3 -       -       -      -

4 -       -       -      -

5 -       -       -      -
```

Comment: Okay, I've fixed the array on the wrong line problem, but how would I enter "-" on each open spot? Later I want the user to select a seat and have it x'd out.

Comment: could you show your sample output and the output you are expecting

Comment: Sure, I edited the original question with the output.

Comment: could you reword you question as the output you have shown has "-" for open seats but you have stated that "**and have "-" marks in each area that has open seats (which it doesn't)**"

Comment: Is that better? Otherwise kindly send me a edit suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of errors in your code.

First for loop should start at 1 end at 4 (both included), so I added an =.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%3d\t", i);
}
```

Second loop should start from 0 (included) and end at n (excluded) or from 1 to n (both included).
So I changed it to the following. In addition for each row you have to present all the seats (4). So this new code:

```
for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
    System.out.print(j); // Print the number of row
    for (int seat = 1; seat <= 4; seat++) {
        System.out.print(" -"); // Print each seat
    }
    System.out.println(""); // Go to the next line
}
```

But this only prints the empty plane.
The best should be print the current plane configuration (with - for empty seat and x for non empty seat). It is possible with the following code assuming that airplane[row][seat] is 0 for a free seat and a different value for occupied seat:

```
for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
    System.out.print(j); // Print the number of row
    for (int seat = 1; seat <= 4; seat++) {
        System.out.print(" "); // Print separator
        if (airplane[row - 1][seat - 1] == 0) {
            System.out.print("-");
        } else {
            System.out.print("X");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(""); // Go to the next line
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just control your fomatting:

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
    System.out.println("Enter n:");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    int[][] airplane = new int[n][4];

    for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        System.out.printf("\t%d\t", i);
    }
    System.out.println("");

    for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%d", j);
        for (int k = 1; k <= 4; k++) {
            System.out.print("\t-\t");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    } 
}
```

There's probably a much clean way of doing this, but it does produce the output you're wanting.

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite you coded as:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AirlineReservation {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        System.out.println("Enter n:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int[][] airplane = new int[n][4];

        for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {//Change here.
            System.out.printf("%3d\t", i);
        }
        System.out.println();//Change here.

        for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            System.out.println((j) + " -" + "       -" + "       -" + "       -");//change Here.
        } 
    }
}
```